# Passing Data(String) from Child VC to Parent VC using easiest Way

Tags: objective-c, ios

Passing Data(String) from Child View Controller to Parent VC using easiest Way .
i tried a Couple of ways , but got lost , can some one tell me the best way .

Comment: "easiest way" - I'd suggest using an Objective-C message send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Srikanth is correct. If you have a segue from a view controller (our "first" view controller) to another (our "second" view controller), all you need to do is to create a property in the second one that points to the first one. You will just have the first view controller make sure to set that pointer before it performs the transition. Having done that, the second controller can update properties or invoke methods of the first controller.

For details, see [Configuring the Destination Controller When a Segue is Triggered](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers/ManagingDataFlowBetweenViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH8-SW4) in the *View Controller Programming Guide* for information on how to set a property in the second view controller (in this case, that property will be a weak pointer to the first controller) in `prepareForSegue`. Then, as Srikanth says, the second controller can use that pointer to update properties in the first one.

So, in your second view controller, have a property (note carefully, it should be `weak`) that points back to the first view controller:

In SecondViewController.h:

```
@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) FirstViewController *firstViewController;

@end
```

Then in the FirstViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifierHere"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setFirstViewController:self];
    }
}
```

So, if your first view controller had, for example, a property of `favoriteColor`:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *favoriteColor;

@end
```

Then, the second view controller could use its `firstViewController` property to update this `favoriteColor`, like so:

```
self.firstViewController.favoriteColor = @"Blue";
```

Clearly:

1. Replace `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` with the appropriate class names;
2. Make sure that your second view controller's .m file does an `#import` of the first view controller's .h; and
3. Make sure you've specified a segue identifier in Interface Builder for your segue from the first controller to the second one and adjust the `prepareForSegue` above, replacing `YourSegueIdentifierHere` with your identifier.

---

In iOS 6, you can also accomplish this via an unwind segue. You'd just have the `prepareForSegue` of the second view controller update the property of the unwind segue's destination controller (i.e. the first controller). What's nice is that unwind segues can go back an arbitrary number of levels, so for more complicated scenarios, it's very nice. It is iOS 6, or higher, only, though.

To do unwind segue's, first you must define an unwind action in the first view controller (identified as such by the combination of the `IBAction` return type and the `UIStoryboardSegue` parameter), e.g.:

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    // do any clean up you want
}
```

Then, the second (or third or ...) view controller can create an unwind segue by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging in Interface Builder from a button to the exit icon in the scene's dock. You can have the controller from which you're unwinding do the logical `prepareForSegue` to pass information back to the first view controller.

---

By the way, you used the terms "parent" and "child", but I wanted to make it clear that I assumed that you were not talking about the more advanced topic of [view controller containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6), in which a view controller is invoking other view controllers to facilitate the presentation of a single screen of information (as opposed to transitioning between different scenes in an app). As rdelmar notes in our comments below, the terms "parent" and "child" controllers, strictly speaking, more properly imply that one is using view controller containment.

Obviously, if you are using view controller containment, then clearly the discussion of segues, `prepareForSegue`, etc., don't apply. Furthermore, a properly implemented container view controller guarantees that the child controllers can actually use the `UIViewController` property of `parentViewController`, without needing to define our own property to reference the parent. All you need to do is to cast/define `parentViewController` to be the right subclass, and then you can access your subclassed properties very easily.

Comment: There's no need to create a property, the child already has the property parentViewController which will point to the parent.

Comment: @rdelmar I don't think you mean `parentViewController`, because that gives you the parent in view controller containment. You can use `presentingViewController` if you're doing modal segues, but in my experience, even that doesn't work if the view controller you're doing the modal segue is, itself, embedded in a navigation controller, for example. And neither `parentViewController` nor `presentingViewController` work if you're doing push segues. (Sigh.) That's why I specify the `parent` myself (and why I didn't call it `parentViewController`, to avoid confusion).

Comment: Yes, I did mean parentViewController, because the question specifically  asks about a parent child relationship. Now, it's quite possible that the OP was using that term incorrectly, in which case your way would be necessary (and more general).

Comment: @rdelmar Agreed. If the OP was really doing view controller containment, then you're quite right, `parentViewController` is an excellent solution. Clearly, I assumed the OP was using the terms loosely (a sin I perpetuated, regretfully), but regardless, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to have a property in the child view controller of type id or UIViewController. Set that value to parent view controller when you are creating the child.

Once you have access to parent view controller in the child view controller you can access its methods or properties.

Comment: Can you please provide me some tutorials link or anything .

Comment: @AkshatAnil: I really doubt there will be a tutorial as specific as "passing a piece of data from a child view controller to a parent view controller. Do you not know how to create properties or what?

Comment: yes i do , but its not working in my case for reason , i trying to use protocols and delegates.

Comment: Akshat, use delegates then. Your child will have a delegate property and that delegate should be set to the parent. Then since you have access to the parent since it is the delegate, you can call or set its methods.

Comment: @AkshatAnil, there's no need to create a property or use delegates, if a view controller has a parent, then you can reference it with self.parentViewController. You would have to import the header for that parent into the child's .m file and cast the result to that class, if you want to access its properties. So, if the parent had a property, foo, you could set it like: [(ParentClass *)self.parentViewController setFoo:@"whatever"];

Comment: @rdelmar is correct. If infact the relationship is as a Parent and child view controllers, there is no need to do any thing additional.

Comment: okay i tried this and i am getting two errors : my property name in parent class "VESRTableViewController"  is "requestorFirstName" ,"Arc symmetic issues no visible @interface for uiviewcontroller declares the selector"

Comment: @AkshatAnil It's hard to tell without the full error message and the precise line causing the error, but it sounds like you're dealing with an object pointer that is referencing a `UIViewController` object, but you're using one of your subclassed property names. A common source of this problem is when you forget to specify the "Custom Class" name in Interface Builder for one of your view controllers. But could be other things, too. Hard to decipher the cause solely from an excerpt of the error message. Might warrant a new question on S.O. if you don't figure it out.