# Modal Segue, get variable from child to be used in parent

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a story board, where I want to connect the child view controller to the parents view controller. the child view will hold a date picker and the value of it will be passed as a variable to the parent class to be used in a function.

i found this on stack overflow
[Passing Data(String) from Child VC to Parent VC using easiest Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829151/passing-datastring-from-child-vc-to-parent-vc-using-easiest-way?answertab=active#tab-top)

but could not understand the part where it said the below. "setFirstViewController"

```
    [segue.destinationViewController setFirstViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `segue.sourceViewController` to get access to the controller from which the segue originates. Similarly, `segue.destinationViewController` is the destination one. When you're inside `prepareForSegue:sender`, both controllers are active and instanciated.

Just read up on [UIStoryboardSegue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation, it's very clear.